# MySQL pivot / crosstab

Tags: mysql, sql, crosstab

I have the following table

```
date_time,channel_code,value
"2013-09-30 08:50:00",no,0.01
"2013-09-30 08:50:00",no2,0.57
"2013-09-30 08:50:00",nox,0.58
"2013-09-30 09:00:00",no,0.03
"2013-09-30 09:00:00",no2,0.59
"2013-09-30 09:00:00",nox,0.62
"2013-09-30 09:10:00",no,0.03
"2013-09-30 09:10:00",no2,0.63
"2013-09-30 09:10:00",nox,0.66
"2013-09-30 09:20:00",no,0.02
"2013-09-30 09:20:00",no2,0.65
"2013-09-30 09:20:00",nox,0.68
"2013-09-30 09:30:00",no,0.04
"2013-09-30 09:30:00",no2,0.74
"2013-09-30 09:30:00",nox,0.78
```

I am trying to get the data in the following form:

```
date_time,no,no2,nox
"2013-09-30 08:50:00",0.01,057,0.58
```

with no luck so far. The database is MySQL, I've read here that it does not have a PIVOT function. Also I had a look on similar posts (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007284/how-to-use-mysql-for-a-dynamic-pivot-table-or-crosstab)) but I guess my SQL skill only takes me this far :-)

Any help appreciated

Comment: Right now I am generating one file for each parameter and joining the files I want using python pandas. It is not too bad it gets the job done but I have to housekeep a lot of csv files, keep track when I updated them etc. I was not able to create a running any running SQL, no. My alternative is to create a table in the form I need and use an AFTER INSERT trigger on the old table to write a line for the second table. This is the best I could do with my knowledge. I thought I could ask here for a better solution, none of the above seem optimum to me.

Comment: Feel free to edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your dynamic pivot query as below

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
  CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN channel_code = ''',
         channel_code, 
         ''' THEN value  END) `',
         channel_code,'`'
         )
          ORDER BY date_time,channel_code ASC        
 )
  INTO @sql
  FROM test;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT date_time, ', @sql, ' 
                     FROM test
                    GROUP BY date_time');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

### [`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/944cb/2)

Or its simple if you have limited/determined `channel_code` then

```
SELECT
date_time,
MAX(CASE WHEN channel_code = 'no' THEN value  END) `no`,
MAX(CASE WHEN channel_code = 'no2' THEN value  END) `no2`,
MAX(CASE WHEN channel_code = 'nox' THEN value  END) `nox`
FROM test
GROUP BY date_time
```

### [`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/944cb/3)

Comment: Thanks man! Both queries work just fine. The second form is very clean I recon I will refer to it many times in the future.